# Recursive method calling freezes Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to call a method `CreateFinalPath()` using recursion but Unity freezes the second time I call the methode `Test()`.

Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

I nearly tried everything , no clue what is going on.

```c#
public class SplinePlus : MonoBehaviour
{
    int h = 0;
    public void Test()
    {
        FinalPath.Vertices.Clear();
        FinalPath.Tangents.Clear();
        FinalPath.Normals.Clear();

        CreateFinalPath();
    }

    private void CreateFinalPath()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Branches[h].Vertices.Count; i++)// branch vertices
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < SharedNodes.Count; n++) // shared nodes loop
            {
                if (SharedNodes[n].Nodes.Point.position == Branches[h].Vertices[i]) // shared node detected , see next branch to take
                {
                    h = SharedNodes[n].BranchToFollow; // next branch ID to take

                    CreateFinalPath(); // trigger data storage for the new branch in Final path class
                    break;
                }
            }
            // data storage in finalpath class
            FinalPath.Vertices.Add(Branches[h].Vertices[i]);
            FinalPath.Normals.Add(Branches[h].Normals[i]);
            FinalPath.Tangents.Add(Branches[h].Tangents[i]);

        }
    }
}
public class FinalPath
{
    public List<Vector3> Vertices = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<Vector3> Tangents = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<Vector3> Normals = new List<Vector3>();
}
public class Branches
{
    public List<Vector3> Vertices = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<Vector3> Tangents = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<Vector3> Normals = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<PathPoint> PathPoints = new List<PathPoint>();

}

[System.Serializable]
public class SharedNodesData
{

    public PathPoint Nodes = new PathPoint();
    public List<string> ConnectedBranches = new List<string>();
    public int BranchToFollow = 0;
}
```

Update2

[image: Spline representation inside viewport]

So what I'm trying to do is to create a final path for a gameObject follower based on a complex path system where there is a main branch (red) and the children branches (yellow) which can be in unlimited number.

The shared nodes are the points with numbers on top of them, I'm looping through the main branch first looking for a shared node, once I find one, I can get the next branch index to take which is defined by the user in an the inspector. I affect that to "h" and call `CreateFinalPath()` to do the same for the next branch until I get the final complete path.

Comment: Where does `h` come from? And you still have a typo in `for(int i 0=; i < Branches[h].Vertices.Count` now there should be a `;` instead of `,`.

Comment: Hello , 
h is a public variable that is set to zero at the start ,but get's changed inside the second  loop once that if condition is met , for the ";" in the first for , it's a mistake i made while editng the file inside the bowser ,

Comment: Is `h` reset to zero when you call the function a second time? You might consider adding a bit more code to make this a complete example so there doesn't need to be a lot of guessing and teasing more information from you.

Comment: Hello i have updated the code above , h get updated only if the condition in the second for is met ,

Comment: You need to explain what that code is supposed to do or what you are doing so that people will help you if they a mistake in your code

Comment: hello ,i have  added more explanation  also as an image to explain more , hope this is enough to have a clear idea on what i'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I didt understand much your codes but maybe you need some things like this

```
public class Branches
{
    public List<Vector3> Vertices = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<Vector3> Tangents = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<Vector3> Normals = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<PathPoint> PathPoints = new List<PathPoint>();
    public bool visited = false;

}

private void CreateFinalPath()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Branches[h].Vertices.Count; i++)// branch vertices
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < SharedNodes.Count; n++) // shared nodes loop
        {
            if (!Branches[h].visited && SharedNodes[n].Nodes.Point.position == Branches[h].Vertices[i]) // shared node detected , see next branch to take
            {
                Branches[h].visited = true;

                h = SharedNodes[n].BranchToFollow; // next branch ID to take

                CreateFinalPath(); // trigger data storage for the new branch in Final path class
                break;
            }
        }
        // data storage in finalpath class
        FinalPath.Vertices.Add(Branches[h].Vertices[i]);
        FinalPath.Normals.Add(Branches[h].Normals[i]);
        FinalPath.Tangents.Add(Branches[h].Tangents[i]);

    }
}
```